# How do I save the output of a function that gets the contents of an external page so I can compare it to the output last time the function was run?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my code:

```
function getstate(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"currentstate.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
      console.log('Used getstate. Output: '+data);
    }
  });
}

function refreshstate(){
    return getstate(function(output){
        var data=JSON.parse(output); // <-- THIS!
        console.log('Refreshed state successfuly. Parsed output: '+data);
    });
}

var refreshtimeout1=setInterval(refreshstate, 5000);
```

How do I save the "data" variable to compare it to the new one next time the setinterval is run? Also can I use clearinterval INSIDE of the refreshstate() function to stop the refresh like clearInterval(refreshtimeout1)?

Comment: Your question appears to just answer your own question. You might actually want to try it first.

Comment: where exactly do you want to compare it?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer what do you mean? If I try to use "data" before declaring it it says undefined even though the function was run beforehand. So it doesn't really work.

Comment: @dietbacon when refreshstate function is used. So everytime the interval is run after getting the new "data" from currentstate.php I want to compare it to the old one to see if anything changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareData(data){
    if (typeof compareData.old_data == 'undefined'){
        // this runs if you haven't initialised compareData.old_data yet
    }
    else{
        console.log(data) // new data
        console.log(compareData.old_data) // old data
        //do any comparisons you want here
    }
    compareData.old_data = data; // old data for next time is current data
    //return whatever you want here
}

function refreshstate(){
    return getstate(function(output){
        var data=JSON.parse(output); // <-- THIS!
        compareData(data);
        console.log('Refreshed state successfuly. Parsed output: '+data);
    });
}
```

the variable compareData.old_data will hold it's value between calls of the function. Alternatively you could create a getstate.old_data inside gestate and use the same principle i used in compareData if you wanna do it inside that function

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is a variable to store the last results that is outside of the refresh state function. So something like the following should work. In order to make use of the refreshtimeout1 variable to clear the interval, I would declare it before the function is declared.

```
var refreshtimeout1;
var lastData = '';
function getstate(handleData) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"currentstate.php",  
    success:function(data) {
      handleData(data); 
      console.log('Used getstate. Output: '+data);
    }
  });
}

function refreshstate(){
    return getstate(function(output){
        var data=JSON.parse(output); // <-- THIS!
        console.log('Refreshed state successfuly. Parsed output: '+data);
        console.log('Last parsed output: '+lastData);
        lastData = data;
    });
}

refreshtimeout1=setInterval(refreshstate, 5000);
```